# Can't login after upgrading to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, login

This afternoon, I upgraded my work laptop from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1.  I had previously had a local account, but after the upgrade, it prompted me to enter my windows account credentials, which I had set up beforehand at some point.  I entered my password and clicked next, went through another screen or two, grew tired with the process, and clicked whatever the equivalent button to "skip this step" that I was presented with.

Now I can't log in.  Not with my (previous) local account password, and not with my windows account password.

It's a Dell with biometric identification, which I had set up previously, so I put my finger on the reader and it complained that I couldn't use that fingerprint because I had changed my password.  But, I hadn't wittingly changed my password at all.  I assume that what happened is that, by entering my credentials, my local account was tied to the Windows account, but because I cancelled the process partway through, something went wrong and I cannot log in.

A few questions:

1) How do I log in with my windows account credentials?  Should LOCALMACHINENAME\username, which was my previous login method, still work for the Windows account?  When I booted to safemode it prompted me with WindowsAccount\myemailaddress, which allowed me to login there, but the regular login doesn't accept the '@' symbol.

2) Is there any way to make that account local-only again?  I can't find any way of doing it.

3) I managed to enable the local administrator account and get back into the box; failing all else, is there a quick way to migrate my old profile over to a new user?

Comment: Try you old local account

Comment: Tried to log into old local account; no dice.  Old password does not work, windows account password does not work.  fingerprint auth does not work.

Comment: You should be able to change the password of the existing Local account by using the `Manage another account` in the `User Account` panel.  Otherwise try changing your Microsoft Account password and login with the new password  http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/change-another-users-password-windows-7.htm

Comment: I tried both already.  Trying to change the local password via "net user myname newpass" yields "The system is not authoritative for the specified account..."  I can log into the microsoft account online without an issue, but that password just gets me an "invalid login" at the windows prompt.  I would still really like to know what happened, or at least how to wrest control of an account back from MS.

Comment: If you are trying to change the Microsoft Account connected local profile then that won't work.  You do understand there are likely two very similar user accounts one which is connected to a Micrsoft Account the other that is not.

Comment: So, how do I specify at login to use the Microsoft Account?  I can type in my email address as the account name, and it doesn't let me log in, and I can type in MYCOMPUTER\MYUSERNAME and it doesn't let me log in that way, either.  I suspect something on the system was corrupted, but if you have any more info on how to actually manage the different types of account I'd love to know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I just ended up creating a new user account and manually rebuilding the profile as best I could.  The Windows 8 account management tools have really been dumbed down!  And the Easy Transfer utility didn't have an option to export my account, only to import an already-exported one.  In short, booting to safe mode allowed me to enable the default administrator account, so I could use the system normally and create a new (local) user account, and copy the files across from the old account.

**Edit: One year later**

It turns out that I had biometric identification enabled, and that was the crux of the problem, as I had this re-occur at least in part after upgrading an account to a Windows Account.  I ended up disabling the Windows Biometric service and removing the Dell data security tools and I could then sign on without issue to a Microsoft account.  I'm sure there's a more complete way of making this work with the biometrics turned on.

Comment: Account management tools are exactly the same as they were in Windows 7.  Which version of the tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

same issue for me after upgrading to windows 8.1 : my password for my microsoft account was no longer accepted.

i used https://account.live.com/password/reset to reset it (hopefully i added a second email in case of).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.
1. always take care you have also a local admin account to solve this kind of problems.
2. It appeared that I had 2 keyboard settings installed and that during login the computer used the other keyboard setting which caused different characters during typing. Since you don't see the characters I was not aware of this.

Comment: This does not even attempt to answer the author's question.